# Test timezone in Django model

Tags: django, testing

I am trying to test a model in django but I faced a issue with the DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) method. I see that since I am asserting equal to the model creation, the message error is telling me that there is a difference of almost one millisecond. I've tried to find the solution but I don't know how to fix this issue. Here is the code:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    message = models.TextField(blank=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Contact {} by {}'.format(self.contact, self.name)

# test_cotact_model

def test_cotact_model(self):
        contact = Contact.objects.create(
            name = 'neil',
            email='neil@email.com',
            subject= 'this is a test.',
            message = 'test',
            created_on = timezone.now(),
            active = False,
        )
        contact.save()
        self.assertEquals(contact.name, 'neil')
        self.assertEquals(contact.email, 'neil@email.com')
        self.assertEquals(contact.subject, 'this is a test.')
        self.assertEquals(contact.message, 'test')
        self.assertEquals(contact.created_on, timezone.now())
        self.assertEquals(contact.active, False)

# Error

self.assertEquals(contact.created_on, timezone.now())
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 22, 19, 0, 54, 413700, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 22, 19, 0, 54, 414675,
 tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I have even saved the `timezone.now()` in a variable also changed the `assertEquals()` method for the timezone after the `contact.save()` command to see whether I could match the time but with no success.

Comment: Maybe [assertAlmostEqual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual) might work?

Comment: I tested your approach but I got: `if round(diff, places) == 0:
TypeError: type datetime.timedelta doesn't define __round__ method
`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I found to match the assertion for the test:

```
imports
from django.test import TestCase
from tour_store.models import Destinations, Comment, Contact
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
from mock import patch

class TestModel(TestCase):
    """
    you will need to pip install mock
    """
    # .......

    def test_cotact_model(self):
        # Add mock and patch to match both datetime.
        # For the model and the assertEquals
        with patch.object(timezone, 'now', return_value=datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 8, 11, 00)) as mock_now:
            contact = Contact.objects.create(
                name = 'neil',
                email='neil@email.com',
                subject= 'this is a test.',
                message = 'test',
                created_on = timezone.now(),
                active = False,
            )
            contact.save()
            self.assertEquals(contact.name, 'neil')
            self.assertEquals(contact.email, 'neil@email.com')
            self.assertEquals(contact.subject, 'this is a test.')
            self.assertEquals(contact.message, 'test')
            self.assertEquals(contact.created_on, timezone.now())
            self.assertEquals(contact.active, False)
```